# Combining vectors by position of elements or indices in R

Tags: r

This could be ridiculously simple but I am not able to do this, what am trying, is combining 3 vectors by index.

Foe e.g.

Suppose I have

```
jj=c(a1,a2,a3,a4)
hh=c(b1,b2,b3,b4)
gg=c(c1,c2,c3,c4)
```

After combining
Desired Output:

```
combine `(jj, hh, gg)`

a1 b1 c1 a2 b2 c2 a3 b3 c3 a4 b4 c4
```

Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `rbind` and then convert to "vector" if they are of equal length as shown in the example.  (instead of `as.vector`, `c` could also do the job)

```
 as.vector(rbind(jj, hh,gg))
 #[1] "a1" "b1" "c1" "a2" "b2" "c2" "a3" "b3" "c3" "a4" "b4" "c4"
```

If the vectors are of unequal lengths

```
 v1 <- c(jj, hh, gg)
 v1[order( c(seq_along(jj), seq_along(hh), seq_along(gg)))]
 #[1] "a1" "b1" "c1" "a2" "b2" "c2" "a3" "b3" "c3" "a4" "b4" "c4"
```

Comment: thank you. That was really simple! :( 

May be I should take a break now.